# update table layout using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a partial which lists Teaching Assistants as dropdown list with few other input fields:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<dynamic>" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="Student.Models" %>

<div>
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Teaching Assistant
            </th>
            <th>
                Course ID
            </th>
            <th>
                Day
            </th>
            <th>
                Delete Row
            </th>
        </tr>
</table>
</div>

<div>
<table id="StudentAction">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select>
                  <option value="TA1">TA1</option>
                  <option value="TA2">TA2</option>
                  <option value="TA3">TA3</option>
                  <option value="TA4">TA4</option>
                  <option value="TA5">TA5</option>
                  <option value="TA6">TA6</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select>
                  <option value="Course1">Course1</option>
                  <option value="Course2">Course2</option>
                  <option value="Course3">Course3</option>
                  <option value="Course4">Course4</option>
                  <option value="Course5">Course5</option>
                  <option value="Course6">Course6</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select>
                  <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
                  <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
                  <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
                  <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
                  <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
                </select>
            </td>
             <td>
            <input id="delete" name="delete" type="image" src="/Content/delete.png"/>
            </td>
        </tr>

</table>
</div>
```

A new row is inserted using jquery every-time a TA, Course and Day is selected:

```
    var clone = $("#StudentAction tr:first").clone();
    $("#StudentAction tr").first().after(clone);
```

Click event handler:

```
    $('input[name="delete"]').click(function () {


        $(this).remove();

    });
```

EDIT
MASTER VIEW:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Student.Models" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Test Form
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<div class="StudentInfo">
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Student Id</th>
    <td><input type="text" name="StudentId" id="StudentId"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Student Type</th>
    <td><select name="StudentType" id="StudentType"></select></td>
</tr>
</table>

<div class="TeachingAssistant">
<% Html.RenderPartial("TeachingAssistant",(object)Model); %>
</div>

<br/><br/>

<input type="button" id="SaveStudent" name="SaveStudent" value="Save Student" />
</div>

</asp:Content>
```

Now when users click the delete image, I want to remove that particular row from the display. How can I do this?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please show your existing click handler. If it is hooked up to the ID, it won't work since IDs are supposed to be unique and you are cloning the element without giving it a new ID (or hooking up the event handler).

Comment: @Diodeus yes, It was hooked to the ID of delete image, I even tried to hooking it up with Name, but even that doesn't work
$('input[name="delete"]').click(function () { $(this).remove();});
How should i approach such tasks? what is the best practice for such tasks? This is a partial view fyi.

Comment: @Diodeus Updated with master view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$('#delete').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: I tried this approach. Clicking the delete image does nothing. seems like it doesn't recognize the click event. This is a partial view, could that be the reason?

Comment: Oh, I see what you're trying to do.  I'll modify my answer.

Comment: still nothing, clicking delete image does nothing.

Comment: Could it be the way partial is bind in parent?

Comment: Perhaps your statement never executes.  You have to execute it somehow, like wrapping it in a $(document).ready(function () {});

Comment: it does execute when i initially launch the website, I have a break-point on: $('#delete').click(function () {...}); and it does stop here when i launch the app

Comment: In `<input id="delete" name="delete" type="image" src="/Content/delete.png"/>`, there is no input type called 'image". Use `<img id="delete" alt="delete" src="/Content/delete.png" />` instead.

Comment: "image" appears in intellisense for type attribute of input element. Also, "img" element is not a button or input element hence confusing to users as its not clickable. However, I tried it but it still doesn't trigger my jquery.